# Javascript Prototype not displaying input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how to use prototypes. I have tried 4 different ways to have my text area and button appear but I cannot figure out why they will not appear. I have commented out the 4 different options I have tried. Will someone please tell me where I may be going wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/FSxbi5X1ri1gXJx5wkNw?p=preview

```js
var PluralsightCommentProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

PluralsightCommentProto.createdCallback = function() {
  this.innerHTML = "<h2>Pluralsight Comment</h2><textarea></textarea></br><input type='submit'>";
}

var PluralsightComment = document.registerElement('pluralsight-comment', {
  prototype: PluralsightCommentProto
});

//#Option 2
var comment = new PluralsightComment();
//document.body.appendChild(comment);

//Option 3
var comment = document.createElement('pluralsight-comment');
//document.body.appendChild(comment);

//Option 4
//document.body.innerHTML = '<pluralsight-comment />';
```

```html
<pluralsight-comment></pluralsight-comment>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: They appear for me when I run the snippet. I am using chrome.

Comment: Ah. I think it doesn't support document.registerElement. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement

Comment: In Firefox it's still behind a preference in about:config

Comment: It's a draft spec, and I think it's a while off. I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: In Firefox, it's available behind a preference, [per the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement). There's a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element#document-register-element) available that supposedly works for IE.

Comment: well thank you for at least figuring out it works in chrome I was just shocked firefox and IE11 was not working

Comment: You can see a good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27751554/5384802